# Ring homomorphism of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring, and $R[x]$ the polynomial ring.
>
> $R\left [ x \right ]\rightarrow R$
>
> $f\left [ x \right ] \mapsto f\left ( 0 \right )$
>
> is a ring homomorphism

I'm having a bit of trouble verifying this is true. Would someone kindly provide some help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Evaluation at $0$ associates to every polynomial its constant term. So you have to check the constant term of $f(x)+g(x)$ is the sum of the constant terms of $f(x)$  and $g(x)$, ans similarly for their product.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for any $r\in R$ the map $\phi: R[x]\rightarrow R$ defined $f\in R[x]\mapsto f(r)$ is a ring homomorphism.

To show this, we need to check that for any $f,g\in R[x]$, $(f+g)(r) = \phi(f+g) = \phi(f)+\phi(g) = f(r)+g(r)$, and $(fg)(r) = \phi(fg) = \phi(f)\phi(g) = f(r)g(r)$.

But the order in which we replace $x$ by $r$ doesn't matter. For example, write $f = a_{n}x^{n}+\cdots+a_{0}$ and $g = b_{m}x^{m}+\cdots+b_{0}$ so $fg = (a_{n}x^{n}+\cdots+a_{0})(b_{m}x^{m}+\cdots+b_{0}) = c_{k}x^{k}+\cdots+c_{0}$ for some $k$ and some $c_{i}\in R$.

Then $(fg)(r) = c_{k}r^{k}+\cdots+c_{0}$. But $(a_{n}x^{n}+\cdots+a_{0})(b_{m}x^{m}+\cdots+b_{0}) = c_{k}x^{k}+\cdots+c_{0}$, still holds when $x$ is replaced with any element of $R$. So in particular, $(a_{n}r^{n}+\cdots+a_{0})(b_{m}r^{m}+\cdots+b_{0}) = c_{k}r^{k}+\cdots+c_{0}$. And here $(a_{n}r^{n}+\cdots+a_{0})(b_{m}r^{m}+\cdots+b_{0}) = f(r)g(r)$.

Similarly $(f+g)(r) = f(r)+g(r)$.